# SQL query - CASE STATEMENT returns 2 or more rows - to pick one value of those

Tags: sql-server

This subquery is part of a large query.

```
    ...
    CASE WHEN tx.call_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'Transfer', 
    CASE WHEN AT.VALUE IS NULL THEN 
       (
        SELECT top 1 product_type FROM [mci].[dbo].[f3_leads_file] WHERE alt_id = '00' + 
           calls.memberid 
        UNION 
        SELECT top 1 'DGU' AS product_type FROM [dbo].[stg_call_routing_data] WHERE alt_id = 
        calls.memberid
       ) 
   ELSE AT.VALUE END AS product_type 
   FROM dbo.cust_call_data AS calls 
    ...
```

Note the 2nd case statement that has the UNION.

```
SELECT top 1 product_type FROM [mci].[dbo].[f3_leads_file] WHERE alt_id = '00' + 
               calls.memberid
```

The first select can return product_type as one of these: **"DGU", "MYW" or "HUA"**.

What we want is if this first select returns **HUA** then use that (it has priority). If value returned is **MYW** then use **DGU** else use **DGU**.

I think the UNION does not help at all here and I should change it to the code below (but then how do I handle it when the value is MYW).

```
...
    CASE WHEN tx.call_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS 'Transfer', 
    CASE WHEN AT.VALUE IS NULL THEN 
        SELECT top 1 product_type FROM [mci].[dbo].[f3_leads_file] WHERE alt_id = '00' + 
           calls.memberid 
         
   ELSE AT.VALUE END AS product_type 
   FROM dbo.cust_call_data AS calls 
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on below statements:

> The first select can return product_type as one of these: "DGU", "MYW" or "HUA".

> What we want is if this first select returns HUA then use that (it has
> priority). If value returned is MYW then use DGU else use DGU.

You want return `HUA` when product type is `HUA` in all other cases return `DGU`

```
CASE WHEN AT.VALUE IS NULL THEN (
    SELECT TOP 1 IIF(product_type = 'HUA', 'HUA', 'DGU')
    FROM [mci].[dbo].[f3_leads_file] 
    WHERE alt_id = '00' + calls.memberid 
 )
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this.